# How can I create a new column in a data frame B for each unique value of a column present in data frame A?

Tags: r, function, variables, vector

I have a data frame `dfA` with ~300 conditions and each condition has many rows containing diagnosis codes associated to them.

```
Condition <- as.character(c("COPD", "COPD", "COPD", "COPD", "HIV", "HIV", "HIV", "Sepsis", "Sepsis", "Sepsis", "Sepsis", "Sepsis"))
Code <- as.character(c("6A61.00", "8BPT.00", "8BPT000", "8BPT100", "E2E0.00", "E2E0100", "E2E0z00", "E2E1.00", "E2E2.00", "E2Ey.00", "E2Ez.00", "Eu84400"))
dfA <- data.frame(Condition, Code)
dfA
   Condition    Code
1       COPD 6A61.00
2       COPD 8BPT.00
3       COPD 8BPT000
4       COPD 8BPT100
5        HIV E2E0.00
6        HIV E2E0100
7        HIV E2E0z00
8     Sepsis E2E1.00
9     Sepsis E2E2.00
10    Sepsis E2Ey.00
11    Sepsis E2Ez.00
12    Sepsis Eu84400
```

I also have a data frame `dfB` with several health events per row. These events are identified with diagnosis codes.

```
Event <- as.double(1:12)
Code2 <- as.character(c("6A61.00", "Eu90z00", "8BPT000", "8BPT100", "Eu90111", "E2E0100", "E2E0z00", "E2E1.00", "E2E2.00", "Eu90z11", "Eu90z12", "Eu9y700"))
dfB <- data.frame(Event, Code2)
dfB
      Event   Code2
1      1 6A61.00
2      2 Eu90z00
3      3 8BPT000
4      4 8BPT100
5      5 Eu90111
6      6 E2E0100
7      7 E2E0z00
8      8 E2E1.00
9      9 E2E2.00
10    10 Eu90z11
11    11 Eu90z12
12    12 Eu9y700
```

I want to create a `column` in the `dfB` named after each **unique condition** in `dfA` (note that `dfA` has multiple rows for each unique condition) that identifies the presence of at least one diagnosis code present for each `Condition`. The idea is - if a row in `dfB` contains diagnosis codes present in the `Condition` `HIV`, for instance, then the `column` `HIV` in `dfB` will receive the value `1`, otherwise, `0`. For example:

```
dfB$"COPD" <- 0
dfB$"COPD"[which(dfB$Code2 %in% (dfA$Code[which(dfA$Condition== "COPD")]))] <- 1

dfB$"HIV" <- 0
dfB$"HIV"[which(dfB$Code2 %in% (dfA$Code[which(dfA$Condition== "HIV")]))] <- 1

dfB$"Sepsis" <- 0
dfB$"Sepsis"[which(dfB$Code2 %in% (dfA$Code[which(dfA$Condition== "Sepsis")]))] <- 1
    
dfB
      Event   Code2 COPD HIV Sepsis
1      1 6A61.00    1   0      0
2      2 Eu90z00    0   0      0
3      3 8BPT000    1   0      0
4      4 8BPT100    1   0      0
5      5 Eu90111    0   0      0
6      6 E2E0100    0   1      0
7      7 E2E0z00    0   1      0
8      8 E2E1.00    0   0      1
9      9 E2E2.00    0   0      1
10    10 Eu90z11    0   0      0
11    11 Eu90z12    0   0      0
12    12 Eu9y700    0   0      0
```

I expect to have created in the `dfB` one `column` for each unique `Condition` present in `dfA`. However, I don't want to have to create a `column` for each condition individually, as I have 300 conditions. Is there a better way of optimizing a piece of code to create the 300 `columns` in my `dfB` for each unique `Condition` from `dfA` at once? The `columns` need to be named after the `Conditions`.

I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: I cant stress enough how strongly I recommend you do not have too many variables floating around in your global environment. I suggest you first put these vectores in a list or dataframe.

Comment: Is you can see from my answer, lists of `codes` may be easier to handle than data.frames here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Original question**
In the original question, the OP had 300 vectors of "codes", each named after a specific condition, in their global environment.

**Original answer**
This solution is prone to errors, as any other, because your method of storing the CID-10 codes as vectors is fragile.
For instance, it may get very difficult to get it right if you have other vectors in your global environment.

As your vectors of interest are all characters, we can first create a list of character vectors:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list_of_CID_10<-mget(ls())%>%keep(is.character)
list_of_CID_10
$COPD
[1] "6A61.00" "8BPT.00" "8BPT000" "8BPT100"

$HIV
[1] "E2E0.00" "E2E0100" "E2E0z00"

$Sepsis
[1] "E2E1.00" "E2E2.00" "E2Ey.00" "E2Ez.00" "Eu84400"
```

#In addition to `keep(is.character)`, you may have to use more complex logic to filter out unwanted character vectos, such as the suggestion by @G. Grothendieck, by size, or with a regex. Something like:

```
list_of_CID_10<-mget(ls())%>%
keep(all(str_detect(., "[A-Za-z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+")) & all(str_length(.)==7))
```

In a second step, loop through this list and call `(df$code %in% .x)`

```
diagnoses<-map_dfc(list_of_CID_10, ~as.integer(df$Code %in% .x))
diagnoses

# A tibble: 12 x 3
    COPD   HIV Sepsis
   <int> <int>  <int>
 1     1     0      0
 2     0     0      0
 3     1     0      0
 4     1     0      0
 5     0     0      0
 6     0     1      0
 7     0     1      0
 8     0     0      1
 9     0     0      1
10     0     0      0
11     0     0      0
12     0     0      0
```

This can be easily appended to your original dataframe:

```
> cbind(df, diagnoses)
   Event    Code COPD HIV Sepsis
1      1 6A61.00    1   0      0
2      2 Eu90z00    0   0      0
3      3 8BPT000    1   0      0
4      4 8BPT100    1   0      0
5      5 Eu90111    0   0      0
6      6 E2E0100    0   1      0
7      7 E2E0z00    0   1      0
8      8 E2E1.00    0   0      1
9      9 E2E2.00    0   0      1
10    10 Eu90z11    0   0      0
11    11 Eu90z12    0   0      0
12    12 Eu9y700    0   0      0
```

You can do it all in a single call, without intermediate objects:

```
mget(ls())%>%keep(is.character)%>%
        map_dfc(~as.integer(df$Code %in% .x))%>%
        cbind(df, .)
```

**Updated question**
In the updated version, the OP had their codes stored in a dataframe, rowwise.

**Answer**
With the codes in a dataframe as in the OPs edit, I would split the dataframe of codes into a list of diseases than use a similar method as in the original answer:

```
split(dfA$Code, dfA$Condition)%>%
        map_dfc(~as.integer(dfB$Code2 %in% .x))%>%
        cbind(dfB, .)

#OR, using `dplyr::group_split()`

dfA%>%group_by(Condition)%>%
        group_split()%>%
        set_names(unique(dfA$Condition))%>%
        map_dfc(~as.integer(dfB$Code2 %in% .x$Code))%>%
        cbind(dfB, .)
```

Comment: If instead of storing the diagnosis codes in vectors, I store them in a data frame, how that would be adjusted in the code? I will edit the post. I do have each vector as a variable in a data frame, with several codes per row.

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the actual dataframe

Comment: If you hava a dataframe of CIDS, you may want to use `map_dfc(select(df_of_CID_10s, where(is.character())), ~as.integer(df$Code %in% .x))`

Comment: Please see my edit which includes a solution with your dataframe of codes

Comment: That is very useful, and thanks for your edits. Just a little correction dfB$Code2 instead of dfB$Code . When I use `dplyr::group_split()` and `purrr::set_names()` the columns for each condition returns with 0 (zeros). I wonder why?

Comment: There was a mistake. We need to use `dfB$Code %in% .x$Code` instead of `dfB$Code %in% .x`. I corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: Corrected dfB$Code to dfB$Code2

Answer (score 2):

Split the codes by condition giving `s` and combine with the `Code2` using outer.  No packages are used.

```
s <- with(dfA, split(Code, Condition))
cbind(dfB, +outer(dfB$Code2, s, Vectorize(`%in%`)))
```

giving:

```
   Event   Code2 COPD HIV Sepsis
1      1 6A61.00    1   0      0
2      2 Eu90z00    0   0      0
3      3 8BPT000    1   0      0
4      4 8BPT100    1   0      0
5      5 Eu90111    0   0      0
6      6 E2E0100    0   1      0
7      7 E2E0z00    0   1      0
8      8 E2E1.00    0   0      1
9      9 E2E2.00    0   0      1
10    10 Eu90z11    0   0      0
11    11 Eu90z12    0   0      0
12    12 Eu9y700    0   0      0
```

### Note

This was used as the input data:

```
Condition <- as.character(c("COPD", "COPD", "COPD", "COPD", "HIV", "HIV", "HIV", "Sepsis", "Sepsis", "Sepsis", "Sepsis", "Sepsis"))
Code <- as.character(c("6A61.00", "8BPT.00", "8BPT000", "8BPT100", "E2E0.00", "E2E0100", "E2E0z00", "E2E1.00", "E2E2.00", "E2Ey.00", "E2Ez.00", "Eu84400"))
dfA <- data.frame(Condition, Code)

Event <- as.double(1:12)
Code2 <- as.character(c("6A61.00", "Eu90z00", "8BPT000", "8BPT100", "Eu90111", "E2E0100", "E2E0z00", "E2E1.00", "E2E2.00", "Eu90z11", "Eu90z12", "Eu9y700"))
dfB <- data.frame(Event, Code2)
```

---

## Old

The question was completely changed.  This addresses the original question.

Using the data shown in the Note at the end, firstly, get the character vectors giving a named list of them, L.

Then use outer to compute the 0/1 matrix and finally cbind df to i9t which will also convert the matrix to data frame columns in the result. No packages are used.

```
L <- Filter(is.character, mget(ls(), .GlobalEnv))
df2 <- cbind(df, +outer(df$Code, L, Vectorize(`%in%`)))
df2
```

giving the following if you have no other character variables in your workspace:

```
   Event    Code COPD HIV Sepsis
1      1 6A61.00    1   0      0
2      2 Eu90z00    0   0      0
3      3 8BPT000    1   0      0
4      4 8BPT100    1   0      0
5      5 Eu90111    0   0      0
6      6 E2E0100    0   1      0
7      7 E2E0z00    0   1      0
8      8 E2E1.00    0   0      1
9      9 E2E2.00    0   0      1
10    10 Eu90z11    0   0      0
11    11 Eu90z12    0   0      0
12    12 Eu9y700    0   0      0
```

### Optional

**1)** One problem with the setup in the question is that there is no sure fire way to distinguish code vectors from other character vectors that may be sitting in the global environment.  If we do have other character vectors that we want to exclude then they won't likely contain valid codes so to address that we can remove df2 columns with no matches, i.e. columns which have all zeros. It will also remove valid columns that have no matches but that may be desirable anyways.

The last line shows which columns were excluded by this procedure giving a chance to investigate it and to decide whether df2 or df3 is preferable as the final answer.

```
df3 <- df2[colSums(df2 != 0) > 0]
setdiff(names(df2), names(df3))
```

**2)** Even better would be to read the code vectors into L or

**3)** read the vectors into a separate environment and replace the line that defines L above with the one shown below.

```
codevecs <- new.env()

# now read code vectors into codevecs in
# whatever way you did before but modified so that they
# go into codevecs

L <- mget(ls(codevecs), codevecs)
```

### Note

The following data was used:

```
COPD <- c("6A61.00", "8BPT.00", "8BPT000", "8BPT100")
HIV <- c("E2E0.00", "E2E0100", "E2E0z00")
Sepsis <- c("E2E1.00", "E2E2.00", "E2Ey.00", "E2Ez.00", "Eu84400")

df <- structure(list(Event = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
), Code = c("6A61.00", "Eu90z00", "8BPT000", "8BPT100", "Eu90111", 
"E2E0100", "E2E0z00", "E2E1.00", "E2E2.00", "Eu90z11", "Eu90z12", 
"Eu9y700")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I suspect something has gone wrong once you have 300 vectors and want to refer to them by name but things are as they are now.

The following code is in itself not a complete answer but it may contain the "hard parts":

```
COPD <- as.character(c("6A61.00", "8BPT.00", "8BPT000", "8BPT100"))
HIV <- as.character(c("E2E0.00", "E2E0100", "E2E0z00"))
Sepsis <- as.character(c("E2E1.00", "E2E2.00", "E2Ey.00", "E2Ez.00", "Eu84400"))


find <- function(diagnosis){
    sapply(Filter(is.vector, as.list(.GlobalEnv)), 
           function(vector){any(match(vector, diagnosis))})
}

find("8BPT000")
find("E2Ey.00")
```

The function `find` searches for all entries in `.GlobalEnv` and filters all those that are vectors. Be aware, that every single value such as `a <- 5` defines a vector in R. `find` will then search for any given Code in each vector and return a vector like this:

```
> find("8BPT000")
   HIV   COPD   Code Sepsis 
    NA   TRUE   TRUE     NA 
> find("E2Ey.00")
   HIV   COPD   Code Sepsis 
    NA     NA     NA   TRUE
```

I will leave it to you to `cbind` your columns in `df` from that.